# Changing Firebase Database Rules from Application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is it possible to change the Firebase Database rules from my Application.
So, I have a User with a photoURL and a Name. Now I want to let the User choose, wether his photoURL can be seen or not. Or only by his contacts or by nobody. I think the best way to achieve this, is to change the rules, so only the Users contacts can read the data, where the photoURL is saved.
If it is even possible... how can I achieve this. If not, is there another way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to change your database security rules. But you can probably write your security rules in a way that allows the use-case. E.g. say you store the user's contacts their sharing setting in the database:

```
contacts: {
  user8633311: {
    user:209103: true,
    user1234567: true
  },
  user209103: {
    user8633311: true
  }
  user1234567: {
    user:209103: true
  }
},
sharing: {
  user8633311: true,
  user209103: false,
  user1234567: false
}
```

Now you can secure access to a user's `photos` node with something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "photos": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "
          auth.uid == $uid || (
            root.child('contacts').child($uid).child(auth.uid).val() === true &&
            root.child('sharing').child($uid).val() === true
          )
        "
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With these rules you can allow your users to control the sharing without having to constantly redeploy security rules.

Comment: Always surprised this isn't more intuitive. Wonder what we could do to improve this aspect of rules.